# Where is the action creator message stored in Xstate?

Tags: state, state-management, xstate

Excerpt from the [assign action docs](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/context.html#assign-action):

```js
import { Machine, assign } from 'xstate';
// example: property assigner

// ...
  actions: assign({
    // increment the current count by the event value
    count: (context, event) => context.count + event.value,

    // assign static value to the message (no function needed)
    message: 'Count changed'
  }),
// ...
```

Where is "Count changed" stored? In the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes correct!

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/trusting-kilby-n3zlg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is a demo in codesandbox to demonstrate it, and a breakdown of it:

I created a machine around the assign action that better demonstrates what will happen:

```
const testMachine = Machine(
  {
    id: "testMachine",
    initial: "lightOn",
    context: {
      count: 0,
      message: ""
    },
    states: {
      lightOn: {
        on: {
          SWITCH_OFF: {
            target: "lightOff",
            actions: assign({
              // increment the current count by the event value
              count: (context, event) => context.count + event.value,
              // assign static value to the message (no function needed)
              message: "Count changed"
            })
          }
        }
      },
      lightOff: {
        on: {
          SWITCH_ON: "lightOn"
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Using the machine in react would look like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useMachine } from "@xstate/react";
import { testMachine } from "./machines";

export default function Test() {
  const [current, send] = useMachine(testMachine);
  return <>
    <div>Message:{current.context.message}</div>
    <div>Count:{current.context.count}</div>
    <button onClick={() => send('SWITCH_OFF', { value: 1 })}>Transition</button>
  </>
}
```

The initial component rendered will be:

[image]

And on clicking the "Transition" button, the event `SWITCH_OFF` will be sent to the machine, resulting in the action triggering, and the count incrementing in the context, and the message being assigned.

Resulting in the component rendering the following:

[image]